# mapping through an array with string objects and render the HTML tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple React application, and I have to map through an array like this:

```
const data = [
   {
    id: 1,
    string: "my dog is a <strong>poodle</strong>"
},
{id: 2,
 string: "my cat is nice"

}

]
```

Sometimes inside the string, I have some strong tags to render. When I try to render that sentence, I will see the html rendered. If I try to use a template literal and assign that strong tag to a variable, I will have the [object object] error.  How can I render tags in this situations? Trying if possible to avoid the "setDangerouslyHTML" prop.
This is my mapping function:

```
data.map(da=>{

  return (<li key={da.id}>{da.string}/>)
}

Thanks for the help!
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly close the tag

```
data.map(da=>(<li key={da.id}>{da.string}</li>))
```

Edit
If you want to display the tag in the string , you can do

```
data.map(da=>(<li key={da.id} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: da.string }}></li>))
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-yn88c?file=/index.js)